# trying to calculate month-over-month percentage growth rate

Tags: sqlite

I have a huge data of 5000 rows and trying to find month over month growth rate for each cities for period June to august. My data is

```
id | host_id | Host_since | area
1    121       2017-08-31   LA
2    243       2017-08-15   SF   
3    243       2017-06-12   SF 
4    100       2017-07-13   NYC
5    300       2017-05-19   CHI
6    250       2017-07-20   MIN
7    135       2017-08-25   LA
.
.
.
```

I don't care about duplicate host_id, the only thing I want is to see total ids created in a month.So I fixed my query but it still says error near "OVER". Not able to figure out what is the issue. Don't know what wrong I am doing as the query looks perfect for me? Any help would be great.

```
Select strftime('%Y-%m', host_since) as month, area, 
count(id) as count,
100 * (count(id) - lag(count(id), 1) over (partition by area, 
order by strftime('%Y-%m', host_since))) / lag(count(id), 1) over 
(partition by area, order by strftime('%Y-%m', host_since))) 
as growth
from listings
where host_since between '2017-06-01' and '2017-08-31'
group by 1,2
order by 1;
```

SQLITE_ERROR: near "over": syntax error

Comment: Should that `cast(id)` be a `count(id)`? For a `cast()` it misses the `AS` part.

Comment: updated. still shows error near over.

Comment: Are you using an old version of sqlite? It only got window functions in 3.25 from last fall.

Comment: And `date_trunc()` is presumably some user defined function?

Comment: @Shawn using sqllite for very first time. Also strftime('%m', host_since) as month works in sqllite.

Comment: made a few changes to my query, runs perfectly without calculating growth but gives  "SQLITE_ERROR: near "over": syntax error"

Comment: @Shawn I am using PopSQL and I think i need to upgrade to premium to use window functions. I have mysql workbench. How do i do it in mysql?

Comment: I think MySQL 8 has window functions

Comment: @Shawn The query worked perfectly in MySQL. You are right the old version of SQLite does not support window functions.